# If use async/await with axios.post it become infinite and ignore code below but result of post is successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have an app which uploads a file on a server via axios.post and multer. Everything goes fine and file uploads successfully but when I switch axios to async/await it freezes to run the M.toast or any code after it.

I've tried to solve it by returning something from the server but it didn't help.

```js
const handleUploadFile = async (e) => {
    const data = new FormData()

    data.append('file', e.target.files[0])
    data.append('name', 'Reservations file')
    data.append('description', 'This is a file with new reservations')

    try {
      // Problem 1 - if you use AWAIT for axios it will never launch code after it.
      await axios.post('/files/', data)
      M.toast({html: "Notification"}) // doesn't work with await, otherwise - ok
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

Everything goes as it should be until the time when you switch function to async/await.

**Server.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.use('/files', require('./routes/files'))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

**routes/files.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './files/',
    filename(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')}-${file.originalname}`);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(res)
});

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Show all the relevant code that *doesn't* work. We can't guess at how it was configured in order to reproduce your issue. Did you make `handleUploadFile ` an `async` function before using `await`?

Comment: `if you use AWAIT for axios it will never launch code after it` that would imply that `axios.post` returns a Promise that never resolves - which would imply that `axios.post` is broken - which, it isn't - perhaps the code in the catch is running and you don't realise it

Comment: @charlietfl updated code. Yes, I used `async` to `handleUploadFile`

Comment: How can  axios  know when the post is finished if your route doesn’t return a response?

Comment: Your server never sends a http response. No wonder the frontend is waiting infinitely.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was trying before to send a response by `return` not `send` :/ thanks all for help <3

Comment: Before complete the process from server never response in await .That may happens for timeout   at server side

Comment: @LDS what did you mean, could you, please, clarify? I think that I got into this trouble? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want your frontend to wait endlessly you have to return a response from the server side, otherwise it won't stop waiting for it.
try this:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({
        success: 'true',
        message: 'upload successful'
    })
});
```